# After creating Managed Metadata Service using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, managed-metadata, managed-metadata-service, managed

I have created Managed Metadata service application using PowerShell. The MMS was created and started successfully. My Question is, Will this new MMS be added as connected service to the central admin site web application by default or should i need to add it. If I need to add this MMS as connected service, then how i can add using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the parameter DefaultProxyGroup when using New-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy